# Pivot element - c++/c

Tags: c++

Program to find the pivot element in an array where all the elements are non zero and unique. ***An element in an array is a pivot element if the sum of all the elements in the list to its left is equal to the sum of all  the elements to its right. EX : {1,2,3,7,6} here 7 is pivot element as 1+2+3 = 6 ***
*Coming to the question, I will be sharing my code for this question. Problem is it isn't working. I consulted some resources but all are mentioning it is inefficient. Can some one please check my code and tell me where i went wrong. I want to develop this code and requesting all to find errors in this code rather than suggest a new code. PS : my first question on SO so in case you aren't satisfied with my method of posting a question please excuse.
Lastly the problem seems to be with my pivot function. Requesting experts to skip other lines of code and validate the pivot function.*

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void initarray(int a[],int n)
{
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=0;
    }
}

void acceptarray(int a[],int n)
{
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter element"<<i+1;cin>>a[i];
    }
}

int pivotelement(int a[],int n)
{
    int s1 =0; int s2=0;
    for(int i =0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(int k =0;k<=i;k++)
        {
            s1 +=a[k];      
        }
        for(int j = i+2;j<n;j++)
        {
            s2 +=a[j];  
        }

        if(s1 == s2)
        {
            cout<<"Pivot element is"<<" "<<a[i+1];break;
        }
        else if(s1 != s2)
        {
            continue;
        }

        else if(i == n-2)
        {
            cout<<"0(no pivot element)";break;
        } 

   }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[100];
    int n =0;
    cout<<"Enter the number of elements in the array";cin>>n;
    initarray(a,n);
    acceptarray(a,n);
    pivotelement(a,n);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you want good help, you should post good code. Format it.

Comment: Return the element from `pivotelement` instead of printing it. Mixing calculation and output mostly causes grief.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in leymans terms that there seems to be a logical mistake, Instead of marking it down can you please send that few minutes in pointing out that error?

Comment: And if your editor is so primitive it can't indent your code for you, get a new editor.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo21 for pointing out the error. my prev comment wasn't for you

Comment: The compilation went fine. Except my output crashed telling me there is a logical error

Comment: @RR2001 You need to be more specific than "it isn't working". Include sample input, expected output, and actual output. Nobody wants to sit and invent test cases for you.

Comment: @RR2001 1) Why does it matter to whom the comment was, originally, addressed? 2) Welcome to C++, if the code compiles, it doesn't mean that it is correct, or doesn't exhibit undefined behavior. Increasing warning level can help, in investigating such issues, somewhat.

Comment: I recommend spending some time thinking about the loop condition `i<=i`.

Comment: @RR2001 *The compilation went fine* -- The compiler has no idea what your program is supposed to do.  The only thing it does is check for syntax errors, and if there are none found, builds an object file.  And there is no syntax error here: `for(int k =0;i<=i;k++)`, so I guess it's ok, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void initarray(int a[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i]=0;
    }
}

void acceptarray(int a[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

int pivotelement(int a[], int n)   //function has return type int so return the index of pivot element
{
    int s1 = 0;
    int s2 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        if(i==0 || i==n-1) /* this condition added */
            continue;

        s1=0, s2=0; /* make s1 s2 zero inside for loop */

        for(int k = 0; k<i; k++) /* k<i not k<=i */
        {
            s1 += a[k];
        }
        for(int j = i+1; j<n; j++) /* j=i+1 not j=i+2 */
        {
            s2 +=a[j];
        }
        if(s1 == s2)
        {
            return i;               //returning the index of pivot element
        }

    }
    return -1;         //return -1 if pivot not found
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[100];
    int n =0;
    cin>>n;
    initarray(a,n);
    acceptarray(a,n);
    int x=pivotelement(a,n);         //call pivot element function and take the value returned

    if(x==-1)
        cout<<"no pivot";
    else
        cout<<"pivot element "<<a[x];


    return 0;
}
```

I have pointed out your errors in comments. This code is working fine.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake.

Comment: Really thanks! Referring your program i modified mine and it worked like a charm. I have a few questions. Kindly requesting you to answer them:         1. Why are you initialising s1 and s2 again in the function?                          
2. what happens when you write continue statement inside curly braces?    3.Lastly regarding address, is there a reason why you are returning i and not a[i]?

Comment: 1- I have initialised s1 and s2 everytime at the start of for loop to zero because after every iteration in the loop s1 and s2 have some value because of the addition statement. every time we start a fresh check so they have to be initialised to zero. 2- when we write continue statement, all the statements after continue statement are skipped, the value of the counter is increased and the control goes back to the start of the loop i.e. it checks the terminating condition after that.

Comment: 3- No there is no specific reason in that. You can return a[i] even. when the returned value will be -1 then pivot element not found otherwise the returned value will be pivot element.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
     int n,hsh=0;cin>>n;
     int arr[n];
     for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
          cin>>arr[i];
     }int i=0,j=n-1,first=arr[0],last=arr[n-1];
     while (i!=j){
          if (first==last){
               if (j=i+2){
                    cout<<arr[i+1];
                    hsh=-1;break;   
               }    
          }else if (first<last){
               i++;
               first+=arr[i];
          }else {
               j--;
               last+=arr[j];
          }
     }    if (hsh==0) cout<<"No Pivot Element";
        
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).